# Reporting on multiple objects

Tags: reporting

I am trying to generate a report for the following data model (Screen shot attached)

[image]

Note
BC is a junction object with a look up to Object B and Object C

2.The report needs to pass information using the red line that I have demarcated ie
Object A >> Object B >> Object BC >> Object C >> Object D
The report needs to display fields on Object D

I have been at it for almost a day and don't seem to be able to find a good way. Hence requesting for help.

Thanks
AJ

Answer (score 1):

There won't be a single report type with all those objects you highlighted. There's two issues at hand:

1. Report types work from the TOP of the hierarchy and let you add secondary objects that lookup to the object. Your scenario is not like that once you hit the junction object.
2. You're limited to 4 objects in a custom report type

For #2, you can add fields from lookups on your selected objects so that technically you have information from more than 4 objects. Not to mention you could always use formula fields on a given object that will give you information from related objects.

Taking that into account and using your diagram you could create the following report types

1. `Object A` & `Object B` & `Object BC` & (add `fields` from lookup to `Object C` on junction object)
2. `Object C` & `Object BC` & (add `fields` from lookup to `Object B`).

You can explore other options to get what you need (without specifics, this'll be general):

- Consider formula fields or before-save automation (flow, apex triggers) to copy over relevant field information from `Object D` into the junction object or `Object C` so report type #1 above could meet the need by having all information desired.
- See if multiple separate reports can be utilized in a dashboard that users can still see the "full" picture.